# Why in JWT authentication Zustand is slow to assign a value through cookies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jwt, zustand

Good morning to everyone, i am trying to manage JWT authentication using zustand in react, but i found a problem when i have to update the access token. I use cookies to store access and refresh tokens.

In this way the code works:

```
async function setFilterHandler(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>){
    e.preventDefault();

     //#region...

     await checkHealth()

     const cookies = new Cookies();
     const access_token = cookies.get('Login').access     

     if (!isLogged) {
         logout()
         navigate('/login/')
     }
                
     props.getFilteredDogs(access_token, filter);
     props.closePanel();            
    }
```

But taking access token in the following way, gives me problems, it's like access is too slow to be updated, and the request goes with old access token

```
const access = useAuth(selectAuthAccessToken)
//this is selectAuthAccessToken =>
//export const selectAuthAccessToken = (state: AuthState) => state.accessToken;

async function setFilterHandler(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>){
    e.preventDefault();

    //#region

    await checkHealth()

    if (!isLogged) {
        logout()
        navigate('/login/')
    }
                
    props.getFilteredDogs(access, filter);
    props.closePanel();            
    }
```

the following function is in useAuth hook, it has to check and update the access token if it's necessary:

```
checkHealth: async () => {
    try {           
        await AuthService.isLogged(get().accessToken)
            .then(() => (set({error: false, isLogged: true})))
            .catch( async () => await AuthService.refreshToken(get().refreshToken)
                .then(() => set({ 
                    accessToken: AuthService.getAccessToken(), 
                    error: false, isLogged: true 
                    }))
                .catch(() => set({ 
                    accessToken: null, 
                    refreshToken: null, 
                    error: true, 
                    isLogged: false 
                }))
             )
     } catch { null} 
    },
```

I hope I have been clear, I already apologize for my bad English, i wish you a good day!

I tried to get access token from auth zustand state, but with console.log i notices that access token from cookies is different from access token in zustand state.
The access token in zustand state is old, instead in the cookies the tokens are updated.
It's seems like set in checkHealth function is slow to set the value of new access token.
Every time i call the token from zustand, i notice that it's always the previous token.